# AX 2012 R2 I don't have LoginProperty class?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, ax, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I am migrating Payroll Module from Ax 2009 to Ax 2012 and when I was trying to fix the Connection to DB replacing the deprecated **CCADOConnection class for LoginProperty class** functionality, I found out that this does not exist on my AOT.

I have some missing class? LoginProperty class should be on my Standard AOT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [LoginProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/library/loginproperty.aspx) class is a [system class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa853470.aspx) and is listed in the System Documentation\Classes node of the AOT.